# Pyinstaller issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I wrote a shutdown/restart/log off/hibarnate system. It's working fine, but when I am trying to use the `pyinstaller --onefile shutdown.py` command (or just `pyinstaller shutdown.py` command it isnt working fine after it. It creates the .exe file and I can open it but it will only display the menu where I can choose what I want to do (and navigate in that), but it won't shutdown my computer (or log off...), and the quit function is not working too.  
Python 3.8.5. (Windows 10) 
(I think the `os.system("shutdown.exe ....)` part isn't working) 
Here is the code:

```
import os
import time

#####################################################################################################
############################################Main Menu################################################
#####################################################################################################
def menu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("Choose a command:")
    print("s = shutdown")
    print("r = restart")
    print("l = log off")
    print("h = hibernate")
    print("c = cancel command")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    commandtype = input(":")
    #Opening command menus
    if commandtype in ["s","r","l","h","c","q","S","R","L","H","C","Q"]:
        pass
    else:
        menu()
    if commandtype in ["s","S"]:
        shutdownmenu()
    if commandtype in ["r","R"]:
        restartmenu()
    if commandtype in ["l","L"]:
        logoffmenu()
    if commandtype in ["h","H"]:
        hibernatemenu()
    if commandtype in ["c","C"]:
        try:
            os.system("cls")
            os.system("shutdown.exe /a")
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            os.system("cls")
            print("*"*10)
            print("   Done")
            print("*"*10)
            time.sleep(2)
            menu()
    if commandtype in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()

#####################################################################################################
############################################Shutdown Menu############################################
#####################################################################################################
def shutdownmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("Shutdown time:")
    print("s = seconds")
    print("m = minutes")
    print("h = hours")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    timetype = input(":")
    #Opening almenus
    if timetype in ["b","s","m","h","q","B","S","M","H","Q"]:
        pass
    else:
        shutdownmenu()
    if timetype in ["s","S"]:
        shutdownsecondsmenu()
    if timetype in ["m","M"]:
        shutdownminutesmenu()
    if timetype in ["h","H"]:
        shutdownhoursmenu()
    if timetype in ["b","B"]:
        menu()
    if timetype in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()

#Seconds Menu
def shutdownsecondsmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many seconds?")
    print("0-60 seconds")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    second = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if second in ["b","q","B","Q"] or second in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60"]:
        pass
    else:
        shutdownsecondsmenu()
    if second in ["b","B"]:
        shutdownmenu()
    if second in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if second >= "0":
        #Shutdown with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t " + second)

#Minutes Menu
def shutdownminutesmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many minutes?")
    print("(Just numbers!)")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    minutes = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if minutes in ["b","q","B","Q"] or "1" <= minutes:
        pass
    else:
        shutdownmenu()
    if minutes in ["b","B"]:
        shutdownmenu()
    if minutes in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if minutes >= "1":
        #Minutes Calculation
        minsec = str(int(eval(minutes) * 60))
        #Shutdown with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t " + minsec)

#Hours Menu
def shutdownhoursmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many hours?")
    print("(Just numbers!)")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    hours = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if hours in ["b","q","B","Q"] or "1" <= hours:
        pass
    else:
        shutdownhoursmenu()
    if hours in ["b","B"]:
        shutdownmenu()
    if hours in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if hours >= "1":
        #Minutes Calculation
        hoursec = str(int(eval(hours) * 3600))
        #Shutdown with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /s /t " + hoursec)

#####################################################################################################
############################################Restart Menu#############################################
#####################################################################################################
def restartmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("Restart time:")
    print("s = seconds")
    print("m = minutes")
    print("h = hours")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    timetype = input(":")
    #Opening almenus
    if timetype in ["b","s","m","h","q","B","S","M","H","Q"]:
        pass
    else:
        restartmenu()
    if timetype in ["s","S"]:
        restartsecondsmenu()
    if timetype in ["m","M"]:
        restartminutesmenu()
    if timetype in ["h","H"]:
        restarthoursmenu()
    if timetype in ["b","B"]:
        menu()
    if timetype in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()

#Seconds Menu
def restartsecondsmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many seconds?")
    print("0-60 seconds")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    second = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if second in ["b","q","B","Q"] or second in ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60"]:
        pass
    else:
        restartsecondsmenu()
    if second in ["b","B"]:
        restartmenu()
    if second in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if second >= "0":
        #Restart with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /r /t " + second)

#Minutes Menu
def restartminutesmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many minutes?")
    print("(Just numbers!)")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    minutes = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if minutes in ["b","q","B","Q"] or "1" <= minutes:
        pass
    else:
        restartminutesmenu()
    if minutes in ["b","B"]:
        restartmenu()
    if minutes in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if minutes >= "1":
        #Minutes Calculation
        minsec = str(int(eval(minutes) * 60))
        #Restart with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /r /t " + minsec)

#Hours Menu
def restarthoursmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("How many hours?")
    print("(Just numbers!)")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    hours = input(":")
    #Menu key fuctions
    if hours in ["b","q","B","Q"] or "1" <= hours:
        pass
    else:
        restarthoursmenu()
    if hours in ["b","B"]:
        restartmenu()
    if hours in ["q","Q"]:
        exit()
    if hours >= "1":
        #Minutes Calculation
        hoursec = str(int(eval(hours) * 3600))
        #Restart with time
        os.system("shutdown.exe /r /t " + hoursec)

#####################################################################################################
############################################Log off Menu#############################################
#####################################################################################################
def logoffmenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("Instant log off?:")
    print("y = yes")
    print("n = no")
    print("*"*20)
    timetype = input(":")
    #Opening almenus
    if timetype in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
        pass
    else:
        logoffmenu()
    if timetype in ["y","Y"]:
        os.system("shutdown.exe /l")
    if timetype in ["n","N"]:
        def quit():
            os.system("cls")
            print("*"*20)
            print("Do you want to quit?")
            print("y = yes")
            print("n = no")
            print("*"*20)
            yesno = input(":")
            if yesno in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
                pass
            else:
                quit()
            if yesno in ["y","Y"]:
                exit()
            if yesno in ["n","N"]:
                menu()
        quit()

#####################################################################################################
############################################Hibernate Menu###########################################
#####################################################################################################
def hibernatemenu():
    os.system("cls")
    print("*"*20)
    print("Instant hibernation:")
    print("y = yes")
    print("n = no")
    print("b = back")
    print("q = quit")
    print("*"*20)
    timetype = input(":")
    #Opening almenus
    if timetype in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
        pass
    else:
        hibernatemenu()
    if timetype in ["y","Y"]:
        os.system("shutdown.exe /h")
    if timetype in ["n","N"]:
        def quit():
            os.system("cls")
            print("*"*20)
            print("Do you want to quit?")
            print("y = yes")
            print("n = no")
            print("*"*20)
            yesno = input(":")
            if yesno in ["y","n","Y","N"]:
                pass
            else:
                quit()
            if yesno in ["y","Y"]:
                exit()
            if yesno in ["n","N"]:
                menu()
        quit()

menu()
```

Comment: May I ask where did you `pip install` `pyinstaller`? did you `pip install pyinstaller`?

Comment: Yes I did it, I didn't set anything special. I just used the pip install pyinstaller code.

Comment: But I downloaded the python to my D: drive, not into C:. Is it a problem? And if yes than how could I fix it?

Comment: Hmm.... when I converted my application to an `exe` file using `pyinstaller`, I had issues with the `pyinstaller` from `pypi`. I suggest you uninstall it and install the `pyinstaller` from their github repo `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

Comment: I tried, it still doesnt working with the developer version.

Comment: I figurated out what could be one of the error. The os.system("shutdown.exe....") is using a file in the System32 folder. Do I need to add it somehow to this project? I think it can't use it like when I was using .py. (C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe). Any tip?